# CWAC Camera - Add tap to focus possible?

Tags: java, android, commonsware-cwac

I'm using the commonsware camera library. My pictures look great, but when I get close to something I want to re-focus, but I haven't been able to do that. I have followed some of the read me documentation as seen here:

> You can call autoFocus() on CameraFragment or CameraView to trigger
>   any auto-focus behavior that you have configured via setFocusMode() on
>   Camera.Parameters. You can call cancelAutoFocus() on CameraFragment or
>   CameraView to ensure that auto-focus mode has been canceled.

I'm simply doing an onclicklistener on the screen, and want it to focus again, so that my picture is clear. Has anyone been successful in doing this?

Comment: "My pictures look great" -- who-hoo! :-) "I'm simply doing an onclicklistener on the screen, and want it to focus again, so that my picture is clear" -- and what specifically are you doing in the listener?

Comment: I'm calling autoFocus()

Comment: :: shrug :: All I am doing is passing the calls to the underlying `Camera` object. You could try `cancelAutoFocus()`, followed by another `autoFocus()`.

Comment: Hah. That shrug. Thanks I will try that and let you know, give me a sec!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, you need to `cancelAutoFocus()` before you can trigger `autoFocus()` again to get a fresh autofocus.

I have [filed an issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/58) with, um, myself, to consider a better API here.